# Is there a conditional statement that would fix my header?

Tags: php, wordpress, conditional-statements

I have set up the header on my WordPress to work wonderfully on the home page. The header is supposed to change to the newest post that I have created and it works.

The problem is that my header does not show up on any pages. I feel that I am missing a bit of code (specifically a conditional statement) that would disable the change and just let pages have the featured image that I set on the dashboard.

The code:

```
<?php

      $recent = get_posts( array('numberposts' => 10) );
      $src = false;
      if(is_home()){
          foreach($recent as $p){
              if( has_post_thumbnail( $p->ID ) ){
                  $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($p->ID), array( 5600,1000 ), false, '' );
              }
              $title = get_the_title();
              $date = get_the_date();
              break;    
          }
      }    
?>

<div class="hero-image" style="background-image: url('<?php echo esc_url( $src[0] ) ?>')">
  <div id="hero-text" class="thumbnail-text">
      <h1><?php echo $title?></h1>
      <h2><?php echo $date?></h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried

```
if(!is_home()){
    result
}
else{
    result
}
```

And tried to put it in the CSS, but it broke.

Comment: make sure `is_home()` is `true`. use `var_dump(is_home())`

Comment: This link might help you, https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/30389/116496

Comment: Please add any clarifications to the question itself so that future readers don't have to comb through all of the comments to get the full story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue with the following:

```
<?php
        $recent = get_posts( array('numberposts' => 10) );
        $src = false;
        if(is_home()){
            foreach($recent as $p){
                if( has_post_thumbnail( $p->ID ) ){
                    $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( 
get_post_thumbnail_id($p->ID), array( 5600,1000 ), false, '' );
}
            $title = get_the_title();
            $date = get_the_date();
            break;

}
}          else if(!is_home()) {
           if( has_post_thumbnail( $p->ID ) ){
                    $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( 
get_post_thumbnail_id($p->ID), array( 5600,1000 ), false, '' );
            $title = get_the_title();
            $date = get_the_date();
        }
        }
   ?>
```